# Can I get an explicit style's x:Key value from a control at runtime?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

If I have an explicit style defined like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle1">...</Style>
```

And a Button control defined like this:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle1}" />
```

Is it possible, at runtime, to extract the style name (i.e., "MyButtonStyle1") from the button control?

Note: I don't think looping through the ResourceDictionary will work because, in our app, it will have been cleared and reloaded by the time this code is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't leverage the `ResourceDictionary` then no; you will need the `ResourceDictionary` to obtain the `x:Key`.